# ssh-keygen .ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory

Tags: 14.04, ssh

I tried to setup a spark cluster environment and when I trying to setup password-free ssh login for user `spark`, I came across this problem.

I create the user `spark` by

`groupadd spark
    useradd -g spark spark
    passwd spark
    mkhomedir_helper spark`

then I `su - spark` and `cd`and then make the `.ssh` directory with:
`mkdir ~/.ssh`
`chmod 700 ~/.ssh`

Finally, I use `ssh-keygen -t rsa -y` to generate the key pairs, then it show 
`/home/spark/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory`.

Yes, you see the problem correct, I'm not asking about `.ssh/authorized_keys: No such file or directory`. I knew that there are tons of posts concerning the famous `authorized_keys` priviledge setting. But this `~/.ssh/id_rsa: no such file` error have almost no information on the web.

Do you have any suggestions? Thank you.

In case it's a version specified bug, I am using `OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014`. I tried stop apparmor with `/etc/init.d/apparmor stop` and it's still the same error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From `man ssh-keygen`:

```
-y      This option will read a private OpenSSH format file and print an 
        OpenSSH public key to stdout.
```

so it fails because there is no *existing* `id_rsa` file.

If you want to create a *new* RSA key pair, run the command **without** the `-y` option, i.e.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

Comment: Wow...Orz, that's the problem!! I thought the `y` option is for automatically confirmation. Thank you!! you save my day, I was about to compile newest  openssh from scratch..

Comment: @AllanRuin yes it's an odd choice of letter since `-y` means exactly that for several other commands